# cannot publish data to my local mqtt server

Tags: mqtt, esp32, sim800

Please i wish somebody could help me with this. I've been struggling into it since a couple of  weeks, i am so new to that.

I want to send data from ESP32 SIM800L to a mqtt broker.
The mqtt server is running on my local machine and the ESP32 SIM800 can perfectly connect to APN.
I saw many tutorials doing it with WIFI connection but not GPRS(what i am using).

I finally find this: [tinyGSM](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM/blob/master/examples/MqttClient/MqttClient.ino) and this :[arduino mqtt mongodb](https://www.hackster.io/14872/temperature-logging-using-mqtt-and-mongodb-a58cce)

And i adapted it as follows, but still getting connection failed:

```
// Your GPRS credentials (leave empty, if not needed)
const char apn[]      = "internet.tn"; // APN (example: internet.vodafone.pt) use https://wiki.apnchanger.org
const char gprsUser[] = ""; // GPRS User
const char gprsPass[] = ""; // GPRS Password

// SIM card PIN (leave empty, if not defined)
const char simPIN[]   = ""; 

uint32_t lastReconnectAttempt = 0;

// TTGO T-Call pins
#define MODEM_RST            5
#define MODEM_PWKEY          4
#define MODEM_POWER_ON       23
#define MODEM_TX             27
#define MODEM_RX             26
#define I2C_SDA              21
#define I2C_SCL              22


// Set serial for debug console (to Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial
// Set serial for AT commands (to SIM800 module)
#define SerialAT Serial1

// Configure TinyGSM library
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800      // Modem is SIM800
#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER   1024  // Set RX buffer to 1Kb

#include <Wire.h>
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

#ifdef DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
    #include <StreamDebugger.h>
    StreamDebugger debugger(SerialAT, SerialMon);
    TinyGsm modem(debugger);
#else
    TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
#endif



// I2C for SIM800 (to keep it running when powered from battery)
TwoWire I2CPower = TwoWire(0);

const char* broker = "localhost";

const char* topicInit = "GsmClientTest/init";
// Function prototypes
void subscribeReceive(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);

// TinyGSM Client for Internet connection
// gsm and MQTT related objects
TinyGsmClient client(modem);
PubSubClient mqtt(client);

long mqtttimer = 0;                 // Timer for counting 5 seconds and retrying mqtt connection
byte mqtttarea = 1;   

#define uS_TO_S_FACTOR 1000000     /* Conversion factor for micro seconds to seconds */
#define TIME_TO_SLEEP  3600        /* Time ESP32 will go to sleep (in seconds) 3600 seconds = 1 hour */

void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int len) {
    SerialMon.print("Message arrived [");
    SerialMon.print(topic);
    SerialMon.print("]: ");
    SerialMon.write(payload, len);
    SerialMon.println();}

boolean mqttConnect() {
    SerialMon.print("Connecting to ");
    SerialMon.print(broker);

    // Connect to MQTT Broker
    boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientTest");

    // Or, if you want to authenticate MQTT:
    //boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientName", "mqtt_user", "mqtt_pass");

    if (status == false) {
        SerialMon.println(" fail");
        return false;
    }
    SerialMon.println(" success");
    mqtt.publish(topicInit, "GsmClientTest started");
    // mqtt.subscribe(topicLed);
    return mqtt.connected();}
void setup() {

    SerialMon.begin(9600);

    // Start I2C communication
    I2CPower.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL, 400000);

    // Set modem reset, enable, power pins
    pinMode(MODEM_PWKEY, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MODEM_RST, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MODEM_POWER_ON, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(MODEM_PWKEY, LOW);
    digitalWrite(MODEM_RST, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MODEM_POWER_ON, HIGH);

    // Set GSM module baud rate and UART pins
    SerialAT.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, MODEM_RX, MODEM_TX);
    delay(3000);

    // Restart SIM800 module, it takes quite some time
    // To skip it, call init() instead of restart()
    SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
    modem.restart();
    // use modem.init() if you don't need the complete restart

    // Unlock your SIM card with a PIN if needed
    if (strlen(simPIN) && modem.getSimStatus() != 3 ) {
        modem.simUnlock(simPIN);
    }
    SerialMon.print("Connecting to APN: ");
    SerialMon.print(apn);
    if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
        SerialMon.println(" fail");
    }
    else {
        SerialMon.println(" OK");
    }
    // MQTT Broker setup
    mqtt.setServer(broker, 1883);
    mqtt.setCallback(mqttCallback);
    esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(TIME_TO_SLEEP * uS_TO_S_FACTOR);
}


void loop() {
    // This is needed at the top of the loop!
    if (!mqtt.connected()) {
        SerialMon.println("=== MQTT NOT CONNECTED ===");
        // Reconnect every 10 seconds
        uint32_t t = millis();
        if (t - lastReconnectAttempt > 10000L) {
            lastReconnectAttempt = t;
            if (mqttConnect()) {
                lastReconnectAttempt = 0;
            }
        }
        delay(100);
        return;
    }
    mqtt.publish(topicInit, "Hello");
    mqtt.loop();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the broker's name to `localhost`:

```
const char* broker = "localhost";
```

`localhost` and the IP address 127.0.0.1 mean "the host that this code is running on". When you're typing commands on the computer running the broker, `localhost` will mean that computer. There's no way it will work on the ESP32.

You need to name or IP address of the computer running the broker. How you find that will depend on the operating system you're running.

If that computer is on your local network it's probably using a private IP address like `10.0.1.x` or `192.168.1.x`. If that's the case you'll need to either use port forwarding in your router to forward packets to it (and then you'll use your router's IP address and not your broker's).

If you're using your router's IP address, that can change without warning, so you'll need to use something like [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) to keep up to date with its current IP address.

You'll likely be better off running the broker outside of your network on a cloud-based virtual server or by using one of the several commercial MQTT services out there. Most of them have a free tier which will allow a reasonable amount of traffic per month.

Regardless, `localhost` will never work here. You need the real, public IP address or name of your broker.

Comment: This is a so clear answer, thank you so much. It is true that i also tested with my private IPAdd 192.168.x.x and it did not work. So i'm going to try with a public broker

Comment: @nadia people accidentally use localhost this way a lot. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

had to read the answer above a couple of times and it made sense. I had  `const char* mqtt_server = "localhost";` which was the local host of the ESP32 not the laptop i had the mosquitto broker running on. As soon as i changed the ip to `const char *mqtt_server =  "10.3.19.254";` (the ip of the laptop) it started to work. thank you!

Also, here's a full guide if someone is still struggling.
https://medium.com/@muhozamy/esp32-mqtt-local-server-tutorial-b706ab0a87ad

Comment: any affiliation with the guide? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)